# Trying to run trianle program with a triangle method

Tags: java, class, methods

[image]
hello, I am trying to run this triangle program and it keeps giving me the error shown in the picture above. the program is compiling but when it time to run it does not run. I have ran the program in eclipse but I cant get it to run in the cmd. does anyone know how to fix this error message? thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Triangle {

int side1, side2, side3;

public Triangle() {
  side1 = 0;
  side2 = 0;
  side3 = 0;
  }

  public void getData(){

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println ("Enter triangle sides in increasing size:");

  System.out.print ("    side1= ");
  side1 = scan.nextInt();

  System.out.print ("    side2= ");
  side2 = scan.nextInt();

  System.out.print ("    side3= ");
  side3 = scan.nextInt();
  }

  public boolean isRight () {
       return ((side1 * side1 + side2 * side2) == (side3 * side3));
  }
  public boolean isEquilateral () {
       return ((side1==side2) && (side2==side3));
  }
  public boolean isScalene () {
   return ((side1 != side2) && (side1 != side3));
  }
  public boolean isIsosceles () {
    return ((side1 == side2) && (side2 != side3)); 

        }

   }



class TriangleEvaluator {

   public static void main (String[] args) {

      Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle();

      triangle1.getData();
      if (triangle1.isRight()) 
         System.out.println ("The triangle is right.");
        if (triangle1.isEquilateral())
             System.out.println ("The triangle is equilateral.");
             if (triangle1.isScalene())
                System.out.println ("The triangle is Scalene.");
                else if (triangle1.isIsosceles())
                    System.out.println ("The triangle is Isosceles.");


   }
}
```

Comment: The class with the main method is `TriangleEvaluator` so its `java TriangleEvaluator`

Comment: yes that worked. thank you so much!!!